# How to animate from UiImageView to a UIView

Tags: iphone

I use Path2.0. I have found that when I click the small picture in a message，there would be an animation to show the whole picture. How does it do that？
I would really appreciate help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UiImageView is bascially a UIView, which you can apply animation on.

The use case you want to achieve combines:

a. a response to touch event, which you can use [UITapGestureRecoginizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer) to attache a block of code

b. zoom the UIImageView into a proper size and position, you can use UIView's class method [AnimiationWithDuration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)....

c. Ultimately, you want to change your UIImageView's frame property to a larger one. use CGRectMake to generate a new one. If you need to take the whole screen estate (like Path 2.0 does), you may need [[UIApplication sharedApplication]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIApplication/sharedApplication).window for this

Answer (score 0):

I doubt they modify the original UIImageView; but a solution might be:

1. Copy the UIImageView (or UIImage)
2. Add it as a subview with the same exact frame as the original image
3. Apply a scale transform on the UIImageView (by using the `CGAffineTransformMakeScale()` function on a UIView's `transform` property (inside a UIView animation block)
4. Then instantiate the root window with a scaled version of the full image

Alternatively, you could instantiate the new subview with the full image, set it with the original UIImageView's frame, and then (using a UIView animation block), set it to the newer frame. To match their implementation exactly, I suggest a black subview (of the full UIImageView) with an alpha of 0.0 that you then animate at the same duration to an alpha of 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest，i was misleaded because i use a new UIViewControl to display the whole picture, the right solution might be:
1：Add a subview (include the UIImageView to show pic you need and others view you might use to do some copy or save operation)
2:Use UIView's methods to do  animations from origin frame to whole picture
3:after the animations, show the picture on the frame
i think it will use, i will test for it
(my english is poor, sorry about that)